# No definition found for qualifier: How to solve Kotlin reflection is not available when creating modules with Koin test?

Tags: testing, reflection, qualifiers, koin, white-box

I'm trying to create a simple white-box test with Koin. After setting qualifier to pass a mock as parameter to an instance (or supposedly what I want to do) I'm receiving an error which says:

> org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for qualifier='null' & class='class com.imagebucket.main.repository.GalleryRepositoryImpl (Kotlin reflection is not available)'

**Test**

```
class GalleryRepositoryTest: AutoCloseKoinTest() {

    private val module = module {
        named("repository").apply {
            single<GalleryRepository>(this) { GalleryRepositoryImpl() }
            single { GalleryViewModel(get(this.javaClass)) }
        }
    }

    private val repository: GalleryRepositoryImpl by inject()
    private val vm: GalleryViewModel by inject()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        startKoin { loadKoinModules(module) }
        declareMock<GalleryRepositoryImpl>()
    }

    @Test
    fun uploadImage_withEmptyUri_shouldDoNothing() {
        vm.delete("")
        verify(repository).delete("")
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class GalleryViewModel(private val repository: GalleryRepository) : ViewModel() {

    fun delete(name: String) {
        repository.delete(name)
    }
}
```

I also tried a similar approach with `Robolectric` runner, but after creating the module in `Application` file, my mock wouldn't be invoked using `verify(repository).delete("")`.

How can I manage to solve this problem and move forward with this simple test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed by Arnaud at [Koin](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin)'s repository, issue [#584](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/584), there should have a code replacement

**from:**

```
private val module = module {
    single<GalleryRepository>(named("repository")) {
        GalleryRepositoryImpl() 
    }

    viewModel { GalleryViewModel(get()) }
}

private val repository: GalleryRepositoryImpl by inject()

private val vm: GalleryViewModel by inject(named("repository"))
```

**to:**

```
private val module = module {
    single<GalleryRepository>(named("repository")) { 
        GalleryRepositoryImpl() 
    }

    viewModel { GalleryViewModel(get(named("repository"))) }
}

private val repository: GalleryRepository by inject(named("repository"))

private val vm: GalleryViewModel by inject()
```